# Ignore element attributes with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the regex below that iterates through a string and then I build an array of script urls.  This breaks if the script also has a type or id specified, is there a way to ignore certain arrtibutes on the script tags such as id, class, type, etc?

```
var regSrc = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"><\/script>/gmi;
```

Comment: I no use jquery because this has to work across a variety of modern websites and applications and jquery is on the way out.

Comment: A bit strong, but fair enough :) Remember jQuery's main philosophy is simplicity and x-browser compatibility though.  I think it's staying put for a while.

Comment: @ne1410s Why don't you write in English?

Comment: Yes but this project does not use jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use the DOM instead. It's much less painful:

```
function get_script_src_from_string (INPUT_STRING) {

  var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tempDiv.innerHTML = INPUT_STRING;

  var scripts = tempDiv.getElementsByTagName('script');
  var script_urls = [];
  for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    script_urls.push(scripts[i].src);
  }
  return script_urls;

}
```

Works in all browsers, easier to understand and does not have edge cases.

Since scripts only get downloaded when the element is added to `document` it won't get downloaded if you never `appendChild` the temporary div.

Comment: the elements are not in the dom in this case they are coming in with a string.  Yes this is terrible but it is the project I am working on.

Comment: Look at my code. The input_string is a string not in the DOM

Comment: Your web browser includes a very robust HTML parser and it's called `innerHTML`. Use it.

Comment: Or is the code running in node.js and you don't have access to the DOM? If so there are also solutions that provides a virtual DOM in node.

Comment: You're right, really need to manipulate the dom vs string now that this is getting more complicated.

Comment: For some reason IE8 ignores script tags but recognizes every other tag in a string, if you think of a fix for that let me know.  Thanks again

Comment: fix for IE8 is appending a character to the innerHTML string then removing the character.  tempDiv.innerHTML = 'X' + content; ...

Comment: Hmm. that's strange indeed. The only reason I can see why you'd need that is that your content string is not well-formed HTML and adding text in front of it forced IE to parse it slightly differently

Comment: Yeah very strange, I went through the jquery library and it looks like that was their fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/<script.*src="([^"]*).*><\/script>/
```

It will match any script tag (with a src) and ignore all attributes but src

Answer (score 0):

```
/<script.*?src="([^"]*)"[^>]*><\/script>/gmi
```

Comment: Almost it : don't use ? next to *
Also, with this regex, `<script src="first.js"></script><script src="second.js"></script>` : only the second.js will be captured

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of the principle (and for fun), I'll give my regex :

```
var regSrc = /<script(:? [a-z]+="[^"]*"| [a-z]+='[^']*')* src="([^"]*)"[^>]*><\/script>/gmi;
```

But the @slebetman answer is the right one and should be validated. (And this regex will not capture the src if it is written with simple quotes `src='path/to/whatever.js'`, but seems safer than the one already given).